# NativeScript full screen background image from an image object

Tags: nativescript

I'm try to place an image on the pageand I need it to be stretched to the full width and height of the screen (background image). The image is bigger than the screen dimensions and is square so I need it to be the height of the screen and centered.

I need it as an image so I can later on move it and animate it.

So far all I was able to do is give my page a background image:

```
#page : {
    background-image: ~/Images/collage.jpg;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: You may consider using the App_Resources images to provide properly scaled images for your app background, app icons, and other static resources.This way you will have properly scaled and nice looking images on all different devices (with their different screen metrics) - for example look at photos used for Android and iOS this demo app https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/tree/angular-end/app/App_Resources

Comment: I have the background bigger on purpose so the sides will be animated later

Comment: were you able to solve it ? I'm using `SVGImage` having the same issue ... svg can't be in the CSS so i'm looking for making `height: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work.. however another possible workaround is the following:

page.xml

```
<Page>
    <GridLayout>
        <GridLayout id="background" scaleX="2" scaleY="2" />
        <!-- page content follows here -->
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

page.css

```
#background {
  background-image: url("path-to-image");
}
```

Use the according scale to stretch the image and from here you can later easily animate your background image.
e.g.

```
page.getViewById("background").animate({
    scale: { x: 1.4, y: 1.4 },
    duration: 4000
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but scale isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looing for height 100% and width will be auto and center the image